# how to parse this json in php

Tags: php, json

hello all i have a json file i.e

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "The Lord of the Rings Trilogy (Official Page)",
         "category": "Movie"
      },
      {
         "name": "Snatch",
         "category": "Drama"
      },
      {
         "name": "The Social Network Movie",
         "category": "Movie"
      },
      {
         "name": "Scarface\u2122",
         "category": "Movie"
      }
  ]
}
```

i want to parse this file in php and get the value of all categories my php code is

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
$string = file_get_contents("test.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
foreach ($json_a as $category_name => $category) {
    echo $category['category'];
}?>
```

but i get this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: category in /var/www/json app/test.php on line 7
```

also how can i get the mode(The mode is the number that is repeated more often than any other)  of category in this file i.e in this example "Movie" is the mode of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var_dump($json_a);
```

Right after `json_decode` and you'll see that array is nested into `data`, so

```
foreach ($json_a['data'] as $category_name => $category) {
    echo $category['category'];
}
```

**UPD**

```
$string = '{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "The Lord of the Rings Trilogy (Official Page)",
         "category": "Drama"
      },
      {
         "name": "Snatch",
         "category": "Movie"
      },
      {
         "name": "The Social Network Movie",
         "category": "Movie"
      },
      {
         "name": "Scarface\u2122",
         "category": "Movie"
      }
  ]
}';
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

$categories = array();
foreach ($json_a['data'] as $category_name => $category) {
    $categories[] = $category['category'];
}

$categories_cnt = array_count_values($categories);
arsort($categories_cnt);

$categories_titles = array_keys($categories_cnt);

$most_frequent_word = reset($categories_titles);

var_dump($most_frequent_word);
```

Comment: Thank you very much zerkms but now how can i find the highest no of repeated word.

Comment: @hunter — While it might involve the same piece of code, that is a completely different question and should be treated as such.